# Integration of EditText with CustomListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-edittext

greetings my fellow developer
i am working on a project in which i have to deal with the contacts list,
i have created a contact list view and an EditText for searching purpose,
my ListView is working as i expect it to, except searching,
here is my listview

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/contacts_search"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_search"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_search"
            android:hint="@string/contacts_search"
            android:maxLines="1" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/contactsListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:divider="@color/colorAccent"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:footerDividersEnabled="false" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

and this is my listviewitem

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/contact_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/contacts_image"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/list_view_margin_vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/list_view_margin_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contact_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contact_number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:textColor="@color/colorGrey" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/contact_check"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:clickable="false" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and i am using

```
SEARCH.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            contactAdapter.getFilter().filter(s); // not working,throwing exception when i do CONTACTS.get(position); in adapter getview()
        }
    });
```

and in my adapter class i have getfilter function, which is not working

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            List<Contact> filtered = new ArrayList<>();
            for(Contact contact:ORIGNAL){
                if(contact.getName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint)){
                    filtered.add(contact);
                }
            }
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            results.count = filtered.size();
            results.values = filtered;
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            if(constraint.length() > 0 ) {
                CONTACTS = (ArrayList<Contact>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

but i cant get the results of search view, it crashes with index out of bound exception where in getView() of adapter class where i am trying CONTACTS.get(position),
any help is appritiated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

greetings my fellow developers,
so i think i have found a solution to my problem, i think that this is the optimal solution too,
i have made some changes to getFilter function in my adapter class

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            if (constraint.length() == 0) {
                results.count = ORIGNAL.size();
                results.values = ORIGNAL;
            } else if (constraint.length() > 0) {
                List<Contact> filtered = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Contact contact : ORIGNAL) {
                    if (contact.getName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint)) {
                        filtered.add(contact);
                    }
                }
                results.count = filtered.size();
                results.values = filtered;
            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            if (constraint.length() == 0) {
                CONTACTS.clear();
                CONTACTS.addAll(ORIGNAL);
            } else if (constraint.length() > 0) {
                CONTACTS.clear();
                CONTACTS.addAll((ArrayList<Contact>) results.values);
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}
```

and one other thing i figured out that id i assign my orignal arraylist with simple assignment operator "=" it passes address of the contact array,
i have used these lines to assign my orignal array in my adapter constructor

```
this.ORIGNAL = new ArrayList<>();
this.ORIGNAL.addAll(contacts);
```

i think this is the only easy and fastest way to search through custom listview, but if anyone of you guys think that there is a better way, please share below.